# Asynchronous tasks in a django app deployed on heroku using Redis

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I am working on a django app. The idea is that the user uploads a list, which can be very huge, the app iterates over the list and processes each item. Problem is that during the iteration, the app is inaccessible. So I tried to make that asynchronous using Django Q and redis. Locally it is working fine, but when deployed to heroku, it does not seem to be working. The Redis worker is running but the iteration is not happening. Following is the part about django Q in my settings.py:

```
# Django-Q Configuration
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'DjangORM',
    'workers': 4,
    'timeout': 500,
    'retry': 600,
    'queue_limit': 50,
    'bulk': 10,
    'orm': 'default',
    'redis': {
        'host': config('REDIS_HOST', default="default"),
        'password': config('REDIS_PASSWORD', default="default"),
        'port': config('REDIS_PORT', default=32219, cast=int),
        'db': 0,
    },
}
```

Please suggest any solutions or tutorials that I can look at. I am using the Heroku Redis add on and it seems to be running on heroku.